# UIRefreshControl block views below

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am new in IoS programming. I am involved in an existing project, and I am facing a problem.
UIRefreshControl is blocking views below. Like image attached (UIRefreshControl is transparent black).

[image]

UIRefreshControl is blocking views below it. But when I am doing some little scroll, the UIRefreshControl is disappeared, and then the button below is clickable.

Here is some snippet of the code.
CommentView.swift

```
     lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        let collectionView: UICollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView.refreshControl = refreshControl
        collectionView.registerCustomCell(CommentCell.self)
        collectionView.register(CommentHeaderView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: CommentView.className, withReuseIdentifier: CommentHeaderView.className)
        return collectionView
    }()
    
    lazy var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl = {
        let refresh = UIRefreshControl()
        refresh.tintColor = .primary
        refresh.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleRefresh), for: .valueChanged)
        refresh.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackTransparent
        return refresh
    }()
```

The blocked views are declared inside CommentHeaderView.swift.

EDIT
I have tried

```
refresh.layer.zPosition = -100
```

but still not working.

Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried solution below, and it works perfectly.

```
refreshControl.layer.zPosition = -1;
refreshControl.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

[UIRefreshController goes over the UICollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003221/uirefreshcontroller-goes-over-the-uicollectionview)

Thanks all!